# Regular expression to split between two words

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression that split all the string between two words .

for example :

```
String S = " ( hey world ) (hello world )"
String [] splitS = s.split(" ????" );
```

so I want to split this String into two String that between ()

Comment: Use ")(" as the delimiter?

Comment: but I want to do it by regex

Comment: show us your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use lookaround's for `(`,`)`

```
String[] splits = s.split("(?<=\\))\\s*(?=\\()" );
```

That would split to

```
( hey world ) 
(hello world )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\w+` or `\w+ \w+` .
It will split words.